# Python: Sorting y value array according to ascending x array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

If I had two arrays of the form:

```
x = [0, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5]

y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

i.e., I have data points at `[0,1]`, `[3,2]`, `[x_n,y_n]` etc. How would I organise `y` for a corresonding ascending `x` value? In other words I end up with ascending values of `x`:

```
x = [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Matched to their corresponding `y` values:

```
y = [1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6]
```

I'm guessing I would need to stitch the two arrays together then sort according to `x`, but I'm not quite sure of the exact syntax for this. Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I would use `zip` with a `lambda`:

```
In [55]: x = [0, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5]

In [56]: y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [57]: L = sorted(zip(x,y), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

In [58]: new_x, new_y = zip(*L)

In [59]: new_x
Out[59]: (0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9)

In [60]: new_y
Out[60]: (1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6)
```

Don't forget to import `operator`

Comment: You don't need to specify sorting by the first element unless you specifically _don't_ want to sort by the second in the case of ties. Also, there's no `lambda` in your code.

Comment: I did it that way, because it seemed to fit what OP was asking for. But I guess not giving `sorted` a `key` might improve runtime efficiency a little

Comment: Sure, it does fit; OP didn't make it clear whether ties need to be / should be broken. I just figured I'd mention it :).

Comment: @Cyphase: good idea to make that specification explicit. As an aside: I'm really not sure what OP wants to do with this. I'm guessing some sort of divide-and-conquer for closest pair of points application?

Comment: Dude! This answer rocks!

Answer (score 4):

You can `sorted` them as tuples after you `zip` them

```
>>> sorted((i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y))
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 4), (5, 7), (6, 5), (7, 2), (9, 6)]
```

To iterate over these pairs, you could do something like

```
sorted_pairs = sorted((i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y))
for i,j in sorted_pairs:
    # do something with each i and j value, which are x and y respectively
```

Or you can index directly like

```
sorted_pairs[0][0]  # x of the first tuple
sorted_pairs[0][1]  # y of the first tuple
sorted_pairs[3][0]  # x of the fourth tuple... etc
```

Comment: And how would I now reference the i values? x[i]?

Comment: Or do `new_x, new_y = zip(*sorted_pairs)`. But if these are single data points, it makes sense to have one list of tuples. You could use `namedtuple` to make accessing them nicer. Or if you just need to iterate over them, use the `for` loop in the answer, with more appropriate variables names (we don't know what these things are, so we can't name them well).

Comment: Or even ```zip(*sorted(zip(x,y)))```

Comment: @wwii, oh yea, forgot to mention that :P. For anyone who doesn't understand, `((i, j) for i, j in zip(x, y))` is returning the same thing as `zip(x, y)`, so you should just use `zip(x, y)` directly. That outer `zip` in @wwii's answer is only if you're splitting the lists again though; otherwise do `sorted_pairs = sorted(zip(x, y))`.

Comment: @Michael Roberts If you need the index values, use `enumerate`

Comment: @saulspatz, that belongs on the question. That said, the OP doesn't want indices; he wants to sort the pairs by one of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I like the other examples (learnt something from them). My answer goes in a bit different direction: it first turns `x` items into (index, x[index]) tuples, sort such list according to 2nd item in the tuple, gets the indices out as a list and uses the list of indices to pick values from `y` list.

Such an approach might get efficient in case, there are more lists like `y` which shall be sorted according to order of items in list `x`.

### Condensed version

```
>>> x = [0, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5]
>>> y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> pick_0 = itemgetter(0)
>>> pick_1 = itemgetter(1)
>>> x_decor = sorted(enumerate(x), key=pick_1)
>>> x_idxs = map(pick_0, x_decor)
>>> multi_picker = itemgetter(*x_idxs)
>>> multi_picker(y)
(1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6)
```

Let me explain, how it works and why it might be relevant in some cases.

### Decorate, sort, get indices, use them to pick result items

First, get the values to work with:

```
>>> x = [0, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5]
>>> y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

then use `enumerate` to decorate value with index of the item in list `x`:

```
>>> x_decor = [(idx, val) for idx, val in enumerate(x)]
>>> x_decor
[(0, 0), (1, 7), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 6), (5, 9), (6, 5)]
```

sort decorated list according to value (being now `itm[1]` as `itm[0]` is original positional index):

```
>>> x_decor.sort(key=lambda itm: itm[1])
>>> x_decor
[(0, 0), (2, 2), (3, 4), (6, 5), (4, 6), (1, 7), (5, 9)]
```

and finally get out just list of positional indexes relevant to sorted `x`:

```
>>> x_idxs = [idx for idx, val in x_decor]
>>> x_idxs
[0, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5]
```

Now we use the `x_idxs` to pick relevant items from `y` list:

```
>>> y_vals = [y[idx] for idx in x_idxs]
>>> y_vals
[1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6]
```

This last step could be repeated for other lists (if we had ones).

## Optimized version using `itemgetter`

Previous code can be optimized (for speed) using `itemgetter`.

`itemgetter` is able creating a function, which allows picking value from specific position. `itemgetter` can also create function, which allows picking multiple values from predefined positions at once.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(0)
<operator.itemgetter at 0x7f8e300afd90>
>>> pick_0 = itemgetter(0)
>>> pick_1 = itemgetter(1)
>>> pick_0_2 = itemgetter(0, 2)
```

Let us see, what these functions can do for us:

```
>>> pick_0(["a", "b", "c"])
'a'
>>> pick_1(["a", "b", "c"])
'b'
>>> pick_0_2(["a", "b", "c"])
('a', 'c')
```

Let us create decorated `x` as before, this time in a bit shorter syntax:

```
>>> x_decor = sorted(enumerate(x), key=pick_1)
>>> x_decor
[(0, 0), (2, 2), (3, 4), (6, 5), (4, 6), (1, 7), (5, 9)]
```

`enumerate(x)` creates the decorated list, sorted uses `key=pick_1` to sort it according to value from original `x` list.

Using `pick_0`, we may get just list of indices from decorated list:

```
>>> x_idxs = map(pick_0, x_decor)
>>> x_idxs
[0, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5]
```

These indices may be used to create `multi_picker` (similarly as `pick_0_2` above):

```
>>> multi_picker = itemgetter(*x_idxs)
>>> multi_picker
<operator.itemgetter at 0x7f8e300afb10>
```

and use `multi_picker` to get properly sorted elements from list `y`:

```
>>> y_vals = multi_picker(y)
>>> y_vals
(1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6)
```

If we would have more list to sort according to sorted `x` elements, `multi_picker` would be the only function to call for them now.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've written this function :

```
def sort_bar(bar_list):
    sorted_x = []
    sorted_x.extend(bar_list['x'])
    sorted_x.sort()
    sorted_y = []
    for x in sorted_x:
        sorted_y.append(bar_list['y'][bar_list['x'].index(x)])
    return {"x": sorted_x, "y": sorted_y}
```

example :

```
unsorted = {
    "x": [5, 9, 2, 3],
    "y": [8, 6, 3, 4]
}
sorted = sort_bar(unsorted)
```